# I want to know the SQL Server procedure error output to be print or know from vba so that i can check my procedure has completely executed or not

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, sql-server-2008

[My SQL Server test procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8im8.png)

My VBA code test goes like this

```
Public mycon As New ADODB.Connection
Const st As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=WEL-COME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=WEL-COME-PC;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=testdb"

Sub conopen()

If mycon.State = 0 Then
    mycon.Open st
End If

End Sub

Sub conclose()

If mycon.State = 1 Then

mycon.Close
End If
End Sub

Sub proceduretotest()

query = "exec usp_datepractice '7/30/2017','7/29/2017','576.test'"

Call conopen
MsgBox "connected to sql server"

mycon.Execute query

Call conclose


End Sub
```

This is my test SQL Server procedure:

```
create table datepractice
(
     TodaysDate Date,
     yesterdays date,
)

create procedure usp_datepractice
     (@datetodays date, 
      @dateyesterday date,
      @datetest varchar
     )
as
begin
    insert into datepractice (TodaysDate, yesterdays) 
    values (@datetodays, @dateyesterday)

    insert into datepractice (TodaysDate, yesterdays) 
    values (@datetodays, @dateyesterday)

    insert into datepractice (TodaysDate, yesterdays) 
    values (@datetest, '09/09/2017')

    update datepractice 
    set yesterdays = '7/26/2017' 
    where yesterdays = '7/29/2017'
end

exec usp_datepractice '7/30/2017','7/29/2017','576.test'
```

I have deliberately put the `'576.test'` in the SQL Server stored procedure to throw an error, now, when I execute the procedure through VBA, the procedure runs partially, and after affecting some rows, it throws an error that I deliberately put in.

Now I want to print or know the error in VBA because it does not show in VBA and procedure continues running.

I want to know the SQL Server procedure error output

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_datepractice, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

to be printed or reported from VBA so that I can check my procedure has completely executed or not.

Comment: Try checking the Connection object's `Errors` collection.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb

Comment: @TimWilliams is this gonna work?

Comment: That's for you to test...

Comment: @user8406687, you may need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the proc.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise, it'll default to a length of **1 character** .....

Comment: @TimWilliams i tried but not working

Comment: @DanGuzman  thank you sir, set no count works in this case.

Comment: @user8406687, I added that as an answer.

Comment: Might be useful for general info: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#ADO

Answer (score 2):

I apologise from the start that this reply is going to be quite long and detailed, but I have seen a few similar questions recently, and it seems to be something that has not received a full answer.  One reason for this, is that AFAIK there is not an easy solution.  This is essentially because SQL Server does not use the same Exception throwing as .Net or Office.  So as you have no doubt observed, even when you know that an error has occurred, no exception is raised in your VBA code that you can trap.

So how do we go about it?  My solution is relatively complex, but once set up, it will work for any stored procedure you need to call.

Firstly within SQL Server create an errors table.  I use this:

```
CREATE TABLE Errors
(
    ErrorNumber int NOT NULL,
    ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL,
    ErrorSeverity int NOT NULL,
    ErrorState int NOT NULL,
    ErrorLine int NOT NULL,
    ErrorProcedure nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    Msg varchar(200) NULL,
    ErrorID int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Errors PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ErrorID ASC
)
)
```

Next create a procedure which all other procedures can call when encountering an error.  Mine is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspErrorReporter

@msg    varchar(200)

AS
declare @id int;

SET @id = (SELECT (ISNULL(MAX(ErrorID),0)) + 1 FROM Errors)


INSERT INTO Errors
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,        
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        @msg, 
        @id;

SELECT -@id
```

Notice here that I am returning the negative id.  This is because my stored procedures usually return the number of rows affected (through SELECT @@ROWCOUNT), which should be positive, so I want an error code to be negative.

Next we create a stored procedure to return any error details that do happen.  Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspErrorDetailsGet

@id int

AS
    SELECT
        ErrorNumber,
        ErrorMessage,
        ErrorSeverity,
        ErrorState,
        ErrorLine,        
        ErrorProcedure,
        Msg 
    FROM Errors WHERE ErrorID = -@id;
```

Finally (within SQL Server) we now alter our stored procedures to invoke this error trapping mechanism.  I cite a simple one of mine below for illustrative purposes:

```
CREATE procedure uspDealerInsert
@dealer varchar(15)

as

begin try

    set nocount on

    INSERT INTO Dealers VALUES(@dealer)
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT 

    set nocount off

end try

begin catch
    declare @msg nvarchar(200)
    SET @msg = ('Error during insertion of dealer...')

    EXECUTE uspErrorReporter @msg
end catch
```

If you want to test my example you will need to create a Dealers table.  This is as simple as it gets:

```
CREATE TABLE Dealers(
    Dealer varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Dealers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Dealer ASC
    )
)
```

Now we are ready for some VBA:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim connStr As String
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim result As ADODB.Recordset
Dim retCode As Integer

    connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbName;Data Source=serverName"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    conn.Open

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter
    param.Name = "@dealer"
    param.Type = adVarChar
    param.Value = "Chris"
    param.Size = 15
    cmd.Parameters.Append param

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "uspDealerInsert"
        Set result = .Execute
    End With

    If Not result.EOF Then
        retCode = result.Fields(0).Value
        If retCode < 0 Then
            Dim msgcmd As ADODB.Command
            Dim msgparam As ADODB.Parameter
            Set msgcmd = New ADODB.Command
            Set msgparam = msgcmd.CreateParameter
            msgparam.Name = "@id"
            msgparam.Type = adInteger
            msgparam.Value = retCode
            msgcmd.Parameters.Append msgparam

            Dim msgresult As ADODB.Recordset
            With msgcmd
                .ActiveConnection = conn
                .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
                .CommandText = "uspErrorDetailsGet"
                Set msgresult = .Execute
                If Not msgresult.EOF Then
                    MsgBox msgresult.Fields(1).Value
                End If
            End With
            Set msgcmd = Nothing
            Set msgresult = Nothing
        End If

    End If

    conn.Close
    Set result = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Now for some explanation.  The ADODB.Command Execute returns a RecordSet.  It is within this RecordSet therefore that our own return codes are to be found.  Usually in my procedures I am returning a single value being rows affected, so the recordset has only one row and one field.  That is why we know that the rows affected should appear as Fields(0).Value.  But now we have the benefit of our previous work on SQL Server.  If the number thus returned is negative, we know that it is the (negative) id of an entry in the errors table.  So we call the stored procedure to load a recordset with the full entries for this error.  In my example I have only sent the ErrorMessage (Fields(1)) to the MsgBox for display purposes (as I usually find this is sufficient to identify the problem), but you can readily change this by adding the other fields as well.

Obviously in a complex workbook with many calls to the database, you would want to put the error display code in a separate sub-routine so that you can call it in multiple places.

If you play along with my example, first time you run the code it should execute fine.  On the second attempt though, you will get a Primary Key violation message.

Obviously you will need to change the connection string and make sure your tables and stored procedures have appropriate permissions.

Comment: I have some very complex ones and use the same technique throughout. All that matters is that each procedure either returns @@ROWCOUNT or the negative of the errorid. Some procedures have multiple statements with multiple records affected. In such cases I sum @@ROWCOUNT each time and return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in the stored procedure. This will suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` messages (row counts) returned by SQL Server, which ADO classic (not ADO.NET) returns as empty result sets with no columns to the application.

If `DONE_IN_PROC` are returned due to `SET NOCOUNT OFF` (the default), the app code needs invoke the `NextRecordset` method on the `RecordSet` object returned by `Connection.Execute` before subsequent statements in the processed. It's generally easier to just specify `SET NOCOUNT ON;` unless multiple record sets need to be processed.